# How to Select-String from Multiple Lines with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, text, select-string

I have this file below test.dat

```
        <category>Games</category>
</game>

        <category>Applications</category>
</game>

        <category>Demos</category>
</game>

        <category>Games</category>
        <description>MLB 2002 (USA)</description>
</game>

        <category>Bonus Discs</category>
</game>

        <category>Multimedia</category>
</game>

        <category>Add-Ons</category>
</game>

        <category>Educational</category>
</game>

        <category>Coverdiscs</category>
</game>

        <category>Video</category>
</game>

        <category>Audio</category>
</game>

        <category>Games</category>
</game>
```

How do I use `Get-Content` and `Select-String` to output the following to terminal from the input of the file above. Using the above input I need to receive this output.

```
            <category>Games</category>
    </game>
            <category>Games</category>
    </game>
```

This is the command I'm currently using but it isn't working.
`Get-Content '.\test.dat' | Select-String -pattern '(^\s+<category>Games<\/category>\n^\s+<\/game>$)'`

Comment: It looks like xml so why not process as xml? What are you going to filter out with notmatch? What are you *actually* trying to achieve? Please provide expected result.

Comment: It is xml but this is the only way I'm familiar with. Basically I just need to strip out
        <category>Games</category>
</game>

Comment: Strip it out and leave the rest of the file? Strip it out and store it exactly like you show there? What *exactly* do you want to end up with? Please edit your post to provide those important details.

Comment: I've simplified it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing is you need to read it all in as one string to match across lines.

```
Get-Content '.\test.dat' -Raw
```

Since it seems you want to exclude the entry with  you can use this pattern that grabs only those that don't have white space after  and before

```
'(?s)\s+<category>Games\S+\r?\n</game>'
```

Select string returns a matchinfo object and you need to extract the `Value` property of the `Matches` property. You can do that a few different ways.

```
Get-Content '.\test.dat' -Raw |
    Select-String '(?s)\s+<category>Games\S+\r?\n</game>' -AllMatches |
        ForEach-Object Matches | ForEach-Object Value
```

or

```
$output = Get-Content '.\test.dat' -Raw |
    Select-String '(?s)\s+<category>Games\S+\r?\n</game>' -AllMatches

$output.Matches.Value
```

or

```
(Get-Content '.\test.dat' -Raw |
    Select-String '(?s)\s+<category>Games\S+\r?\n</game>' -AllMatches).Matches.Value
```

Output

```
        <category>Games</category>
</game>


        <category>Games</category>
</game>
```

You could also use `[regex]` type accelerator.

```
$str = Get-Content '.\test.dat' -Raw

[regex]::Matches($str,'(?s)\s+<category>Games\S+\r?\n</game>').value
```

**EDIT**

Based on your additional info, the way I understand it is you want to remove any game categories that are empty. We can simplify this greatly by using a here string.

```
$pattern = @'
        <category>Games</category>
    </game>

'@
```

The additional blank line is intentional to capture the final newline character. You could also write it like this

```
$pattern = @'
        <category>Games</category>
    </game>\r?\n
'@
```

Now if we do a replace on the pattern, you'll see what I believe is what you expect for your final result.

```
(Get-Content $inputfile -Raw) -replace $pattern
```

And to finish it off you can just put the above command inside a `Set-Content` command. Since the `Get-Content` command is enclosed in parenthesis, it is completely read into memory before the file is written to.

```
Set-Content -Path $inputfile -Value ((Get-Content $inputfile -Raw) -replace $pattern)
```

**EDIT 2**

Well it seems to work in ISE but not in powershell console. In case you encounter the same thing, try this.

```
$pattern = '(?s)\s+<category>Games</category>\r?\n\s+</game>'

Set-Content -Path $inputfile -Value ((Get-Content $inputfile -Raw) -replace $pattern)
```

Comment: So this is ending up to be way more complicated than I thought it should be. This works on the test file fine but the real file I want it on isn't. I've created a pastebin since the file is very large. but this is the data I"m working with https://pastebin.com/q33wFdAX.

What is the best way to automate just removing those dual lines from the file?

Comment: Basically I wanted to use -notmatch to get everything but         <category>Games</category></game> so I could just write a newfile without those lines. This is real easy in notepad++ but I was looking for a way to automate it.

Comment: But you do want to leave the game section with MLB?

Comment: Yes the game sections with data I would want to keep. If it's empty then no

Comment: Edit 2 Pretty much hits the nail on the head. Thank you so much. Curious how would I go about doing an or with that pattern? I tried `'(?s)(\s+<category>Games</category>\r?\n\s+</game>)|(<category>Demos</category>\r?\n\s+</game>)'` and while that does work it leaves some empty lines in Demos place. Probably going to run this in a scrip anyway so I can also just do multiple lines for each that I need removed.

Comment: Just add an extra \r?\n at the end